# Is it possible to open Navigation slider from right side on click of lsat item of bottom navigation

Tags: android

I have used Bottom Navigation, on click of end options menu (say 'More') I want to open navigation Slider from Right side of screen. Is it possible? If yes, then how to do this?

Comment: yes possible, try mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

Comment: set Gravity as right

Comment: thank you for ans but I already tried to set gravity and it is working also but then other Fragments UI attached to baseActivity/ Bottom Navigation's other option's(Like Home) UI  is changing when I open drawer.